# Как создать свой компонент для windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, компоненты

Необходимо создать компоненты для windows forms на C#, как визуальный так и не визуальный. С чего начать и как это сделать?

Comment: Это вы в каком-нибудь учебном заведении проходите WinForms, или это вам по работе?

Comment: В университете изучаем @VladfromMoscow

Comment: Ищите книгу Павла Агурова "C# Разработка компонентов в MS Visual Studio 2005/2008".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Наверное, с теории. А в этом отношении лучше [начать с MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/5dya64wy(v=vs.120).aspx). Привожу ссылку, т.к. объем информации очень не малый, плюс там есть практические и пошаговые руководства. Для начала, вероятно, достаточно.

UPD. Вообще тема доволно обширная, по ней даже книги пишут, но в качестве простой иллюстрации вот еще [статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/170375/) с пошаговым созданием визуального компонента.